# how to use @Valid and @Pattern (regexp="...") annotation together to save encoded password

Tags: java, regex, spring-boot, hibernate, validation

I am doing password validation. I have used `@Pattern(regexp = "^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#&()–[{}]:;',?/*~$^+=<>]).{8,20}$")` in Entity class and **@Valid** annotation in Controller. It is working fine when I am not encoding the password in Service class but if I am encoding the password and try to **save** it is throwing '**javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException**'.

Code in Service class-->

```
user.setPassword(emailTemplateSecurityService.passwordEncoder().encode(user.getPassword()));
        User savedUser = userDao.save(user);
        log.info("User details saved with userId: {}", savedUser.getUserId());
        return savedUser;
```

Code in Entity class-->

```
@Pattern(regexp = "^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#&()–[{}]:;',?/*~$^+=<>]).{8,20}$", 
         message = "Invalid Password pattern. Password must contain 8 to 20 characters at least one digit, lower, upper case and one special character."
         )
    private String password;
```

Comment: Does it work, if you use a simpler pattern? Like `^.*$`? What is the most simple pattern, that reproduces your issue?

Comment: Is your Entity used in your presentation layer? It's a good practice to use DTOs between your presentation layer and your business logic layer.